# Send Email with table format body from a text file

Tags: shell-script, email

I have a text file which is generated by some process.
The file has 5 columns and 3 records as of now. The number of records can increase later.

I want the simplest way to convert those rows and columns in the tabular format and send it in the mail.

I have already checked a number of posts like below but nowhere it is meeting my exact requirement.

[Send Mail HTML Table body & Attachment Text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497294/send-mail-html-table-body-attachment-text-file)

[Send mail with an attachment and body of mail with table format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428805/send-mail-with-an-attachment-and-body-of-mail-with-table-format)

I saw various posts to implement multipart mail but i couldn't understand much.
Is there a simpler way or is multipart way the only approach?

```
File :
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Abc,0,5000,4500,True
bcd,1,9000,3000,False
DGF,3,4000,2000,True
```

This file I want to send in mail as a table.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Do you need an HTML-formatted table, or will plain text be sufficient?

Comment: I want tabular format in the mail body. The table should have the columns and rows from the text file which is generated.

Comment: Please refer to my answer, if it fits your need please accept it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

if your source is a file with the following content

```
Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Abc,0,5000,4500,True
bcd,1,9000,3000,False
DGF,3,4000,2000,True
```

The below script will create create a html file with a table

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$','
first=1
echo '<table>'
while read -r cola colb colc cold colf; do
    [[ $first == 1 ]] && element=th || element=td
    first=0
    echo "<tr><$element>$cola</$element><$element>$colb</$element><$element>$colc</$element><$element>$cold</$element><$element>$colf</$element></tr>"
done < $1
echo '</table>'
```

To execute you need to create a **.sh** file and paste the script inside. Set its mode to execute

```
chmod +x your_script.sh
```

and then execute the script directing the output to a files (**example: output.html**)

```
./your_script.sh your_source_file > output.html
```

when its done your output should be like this

[image]

To send the email you can use the following

```
sendemail -s stmp:port -xu user -xp pass -f account_from -t destination_account -u subject -m "your_html_message" -o message-header="From: your name <account_from>" -o message-content-type=html -o message-charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks Banjosa, let me run that and get back to you. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I do not want to pass the input file to the script, rather i would like to specify the path and the file name in my script only along with the email notification logic.

Comment: so you want the location of the source file to be hardcoded in the script?

Comment: yes that will be fine

Comment: just change the done < $1 to done < /path_to_your_source_file

Comment: In ur sendmail code where are u refrerring to the output.html?

Comment: in -m "your_html_message"

Comment: so can i use -m output.html ?